# Creating a tag cloud out of taglink?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, tag-cloud

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 to create a blog and I want to create a tagCloud for it.

Now my question is how I get it into a list (do I need to?), count and then print it out in different sizes?

EDIT:

I have now able to count every tag in every post with following:

```
Dictionary<string, int> tagLista = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (Post post in Model)
    {
        foreach (Tag tag in post.Tags)
        {
            if (!tagLista.ContainsKey(tag.Name))
            {
                tagLista[tag.Name] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                tagLista[tag.Name] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //Print out diff. sizes depending on count
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in tagLista)
    {

        if (pair.Value <= 2)
        {
                        <a class="minSize" href="@Href("~/Posts/Tags/" + pair.Key)">@pair.Key</a>
        }

        if (pair.Value > 2 && pair.Value <= 4)
        {
                        <a class="medSize" href="@Href("~/Posts/Tags/" + pair.Key)">@pair.Key</a>
        }
        if (pair.Value > 4 && pair.Value >= 6)
        {
                        <a class="maxSize" href="@Href("~/Posts/Tags/" + pair.Key)">@pair.Key</a> 
        }
    }
```

The problem here is now that it only shows the tags of all posts on the current page, and not all tags from the database. How should I do instead? On the top of this view(Index) I use:

```
@using Blog.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Post>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now able to count every tag in every post with following:

```
Dictionary<string, int> tagLista = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (Post post in Model)
{
    foreach (Tag tag in post.Tags)
    {
        if (!tagLista.ContainsKey(tag.Name))
        {
            tagLista[tag.Name] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            tagLista[tag.Name] += 1;
        }
    }
}
//Print out diff. sizes depending on count
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in tagLista)
{

    if (pair.Value <= 2)
    {
                    <a class="minSize" href="@Href("~/Posts/Tags/" + pair.Key)">@pair.Key</a>
    }

    if (pair.Value > 2 && pair.Value <= 4)
    {
                    <a class="medSize" href="@Href("~/Posts/Tags/" + pair.Key)">@pair.Key</a>
    }
    if (pair.Value > 4 && pair.Value >= 6)
    {
                    <a class="maxSize" href="@Href("~/Posts/Tags/" + pair.Key)">@pair.Key</a> 
    }
}
```

The problem here is now that it only shows the tags of all posts on the current page, and not all tags from the database. How should I do instead? On the top of this view(Index) I use:

```
@using Blog.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Post>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test this but I hope this works anyways:

```
var list = Model.SelectMany(x => x.Tags).GroupBy(x => x.Name, g => new {Name = g.Key, Amount = g.Count()});
```

returns a list with Tag Names and their respective amounts.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm really new with MVC3 so I don't really understand what you just wrote. Can you elaborate? I've come with an solution on the comment below....but I got a new problem that I think you have a clue about!

Comment: Basically it is a LINQ-Query (written in form of anonymous lambda functions, I prefer this syntax). The first method, SelectMany, will get all the collections of Tags and then make one big array out of them. The GroupBy-method works like SQL Group By, it groups by the property Name and then calculates the Amount of Tags which have been grouped using Count().

Comment: Thanks alot for your description! It's a little mess to work with ASP.NET when I'm used to traditional one. Can you see why my code doesn't collect all tags from database?  It only shows the tags on current page...

Comment: Apparently your Controller only gives your View the posts of the current page, so you need to change the Controller to also give the view the tagcloud. You can give the view several variables like this: return View(new Tuple(Posts, TagCloud)); In the view, you'd then need to access Model.Item1 and Model.Item2 respectively (Or if you want to do it cleanly, create a View-Model and return just that)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://github.com/addywaddy/jquery.tagcloud.js/) jquery plugin. Basically you should group all the posts based on tags.

```
<div id="tagCloud">
  foreach(var tag in Tags)
  {
    <a href="@tag.Path()" rel="@tag.Posts.Count">@tag.Name</a>
  }
</div>

$.fn.tagcloud.defaults = {
  size: {start: 14, end: 18, unit: 'pt'},
  color: {start: '#cde', end: '#f52'}
};

$(function () {
  $('#tagCloud a').tagcloud();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! I prefer not to use JQuery in this but I do understand the idea!